# Get list of empty folders older then x days

Tags: batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I need to get a list of empty folders in a given location, older then x days. Using "forfiles" I'm able to get all older folders, but not the empty ones. Using "for" I'm able to get all empty folders, but I can't seem to set the older ones.

Get empty folders:

```
@for /r "c:\FileStore" /d %F in (.) do @(dir /b "%F" | findstr "^" >nul || echo %~fF)
```

Get older folders:

```
 ForFiles /p "C:\FileStore" /s /d -3 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo @path"
```

How do I combine these 2 commands?

Comment: I'm removing the `bash` tag. I suspect you meant `batch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotation marks of the part `findstr "^"` for `forfiles`. There is the way `\"`, but I do not recommend this, because the `"` are still recognised by the command interpreter `cmd` (user [Ben Personick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3985011) shows how to do this in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56796531) though). Anyway, I would use `0x22` instead in order to hide the quotes from `cmd`, like this:

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "C:\FileStore" /D -3 /C "cmd /C if @ISDIR == TRUE (dir /B /A @PATH | findstr 0x22^0x22 > nul || echo @PATH)"
```

Instead of [`findstr "^"`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) you could also use [`find /V ""`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html):

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "C:\FileStore" /D -3 /C "cmd /C if @ISDIR == TRUE (dir /B /A @PATH | find /V 0x220x22 > nul || echo @PATH)"
```

But the easiest way is to use [`set /P`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html):

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "C:\FileStore" /D -3 /C "cmd /C if @ISDIR == TRUE (dir /B /A @PATH | set /P _= || echo @PATH)"
```

*N. B.:*
`forfiles` only regards the date (not the time) of the last modification, but not the creation date/time.

Comment: Thanks. It works great. Performance wise, is there any prefered solution?

Comment: Not really, since `forfiles` is really slow, because it opens a new `cmd` instance for every loop iteration...

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest hurdle is escaping the double quotes in the FindStr and the Carrot needing doubling too (or it will stop the following quote from being escaped.)

Hmm strange I thought you asked to delete these directories, since you haven't I'll amend it as such.

```
ForFiles /P "c:\FileStore" /d -3 /C "CMD /C if @isdir==TRUE ( DIR /B @Path | FindStr \"^^\" >NUL || ECHO Empty Folder: @Path )"
```

Also since you are only looking for a list of those it does make sense to kill the output from the FindStr so I added the `>Nul` back in.

Again not sure how I ot it into my head that you wanted to remove the empty folders older than 3 days old, since there isn't such a requirement, the portion about needing to re-run the command is moot and I've remove dit for now.

Comment: Nice escaping sequence, +1! you should add `> nul` to `findstr` to avoid confusing output, and you should perhaps remove `rd`, because the question does not say anything about removing directories...

Comment: thanks, the hex on your answer is interesting, I haven't seen that before, I thought only SET would interpret hex as actually being hex.  Your right about the delete, I read it this morning, and would have sworn he asked to delete the empty directories.

Comment: The hex. notation `0xHH` of character codes is `forfiles`-specific -- type `forfiles /?`; though I'm not sure whether former versions of the command also featured this. Oh, maybe it was a bit too early... no, just kidding... if they really want to delete empty directories, they wouldn't have to check if they're empty since plain `rd` doesn't remove directories with any contents (but what if a directory only contains empty directories: if these are deleted, the parent is empty too, so delete also? anyway, that's a situation only the OP could clarify)...

Comment: Yes I actually started to note it in the original post about RD but decided it wasn ot necessary, and yes, with the chains of empty directories they would have to do more runs of the program or  add more logic.

Comment: I avoid forfiles often times myself preferring `for /r` `for /f` and/or `Robocopy`  mostly or powershell more-so these days.  I don't particularly think they implemented their methodology very nicely with Forfiles, and there is a flaw on certain version which causes the Date comparison to be done incorrectly (so most often the reason I'll use Robocopy even if not copying)

Comment: I guess you're talking about `forfiles /D +days` pointing into the future, right? oh yes, I hate this flaw! you're right, `robocopy` is better in these matters...

Comment: Yeah, its annoying that for CMD line utilities bugs, once introduced, are rarely addressed.  Robocopy is one of the few which has had bugs fixed and missing features addressed.  I think this is likely because internally to Microsoft those commands which are used by them are more likely to have bugs found and features improved.